# why do we need BindToController in Custom directive

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

why do we need BindToController in Custom directive. What this syntax provides which we can not achieve without using it. I have gone through so many docs but did not get my answer. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Also why do we create Controller in directive.

Answer (score 2):

Angular has been trying to move users away from putting data directly on $scope and instead putting the data into controllers instead. One of the primary motivations for this is because controllers are just plain classes, and are much easier to unit test.

Also, using a controller instead of just using the link function is primarily for the same reasons. The link function should only be used for DOM manipulation and other things that are non-angular, like wrapping a jquery plugin or subscribing to DOM events directly.

So putting all of that together, here is the preferred way to create a custom directive

```
angular.module('app').directive('person', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: PersonDirectiveController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true,
    scope: {
      'age': '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {

    }
  };

});

function PersonDirectiveController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.name = 'Bob';
  //vm.age is passed in through scope and because of bindToController
}
```

now we can simply test the PersonDirectiveController directly rather than having to deal with $scope

```
describe('PersonDirectiveController', function() {
  it('has a name', function() {
    var vm = new PersonDirectiveController();
    expect(vm.name).toEqual('Bob');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use controllerAs syntax inside a directive  Starting with Angular 1.3 you’ll also need to add a `bindToController` property as well to ensure that properties are bound to the controller rather than to the scope. 
Lets have an example:

```
(function() {

 var app = angular.module('directivesModule');

 app.directive('isolateScopeWithControllerAs', function () {

  var controller = function () {

          var vm = this;

          vm.items = {}

          vm.addItem = function () {
              //Add new customer to directive scope
              vm.items.push({
                  name: 'New Directive Controller Item'
              });
          };
  };    

  var template = '<button ng-click="vm.addItem()">Add Item</button>' +
                 '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in vm.items">{{ ::item.name     }}</li></ul>';

  return {
      restrict: 'EA', //Default for 1.3+
      scope: {
          datasource: '=',
          add: '&',
      },
      controller: controller,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true, //required in 1.3+ with controllerAs
      template: template
    };
  });

 }());
```

In this controller alias of `vm` is assigned to the `controllerAs` property and the alias is used in the controller code and in the view. The `bindToController` property is set to true to ensure that properties are bound to the controller instead of the scope.